# Yii2 two submitButtons going to wrong URL

Tags: php, html, yii2

I have a form with a modal window where you can submit extra data to be input into the form. The modal has its own 'submit' button separate from the submit button on the main form.

The problem is, when I click the submit button on the modal, it goes back to the previous page. The data still gets submitted, but it's not much use since the user will now be on the wrong page.

I tried specifying a 'url' option in the button:

```
Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary','url' => myUrl]);
```

But for some reason this prevented the main form from being submitted, i.e. that submit button just wouldn't work. Are the two linked somehow? Do I need to make the modal submit button point to a specific Url? Ideally I just want it to stay on the page after closing the modal.

Edit:

The modal gets loaded through JavaScript:

```
.find("#clientModalContent")
        .load($(this).attr('value'));
```

I then have a separate php file with the actual content of the modal, namely some fields and the submit button. This gets rendered by an action in my Controller, and I am using the 'renderAjax' method:

```
return $this->renderAjax('modalcreateclient', [
            'model' => $model
            ]);
```

The modal actually gets called when the user clicks a button (Html::button), with an id that the js can pick up to load it.

Comment: Could you provide more code?

Comment: you cant sumbit two forms simultaneously. you should use Ajax technology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have two buttons submit but one ActiveForm and then a single destination for both actions submit.
Yet you need to have two separate ActiveForm each with a unique submit.

To do this you have to assign a correct ActiveForm also modal in which you submit the second and assign to this ActiveForm method and the action you care about such as

```
<php  $form = ActiveForm::begin([
      'method' => 'posts',
      'action' => ['yourController/youAction'],
       .......
 ]); ?>


<?= $form->field($model, 'surname')->textInput(['maxlength' => 64]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => 32]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'zipcode')->textInput(['maxlength' => 4]) ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'save'), ['class' =>  'btn btn-primary' ]) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: I was already using 2 ActiveForms, but you were right about putting an 'action' => ['myController/myAction'] inside it, that at least lets me stay on the page by getting the id of the client in question and 'redirecting' to there. 
Kind of a roundabout way of doing it, but at least it works!